# Conditional Join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, conditional-statements

Consider below 3 tables.

## Table a

```
Col a   Col b   Col c
1   000 Actual data
1   001 Actual data
2   000 Actual data
3   000 Actual data
3   001 Actual data
3   002 Actual data
```

Table b

```
Col a   Col b   Col d
1   000 Actual data
1   001 Actual data
2   000 Actual data

Table c
Col a   Col b   Col d
3   000 Actual data
3   001 Actual data
3   002 Actual data
```

Table a is parent table and table b and c are child table having col a & b common among 3 and needs to be joined.

Now Join should be such if data is not found in table b then only it should be searched in table c

Desired:
cola    col b   col c   col d
1   000 somedata    moredata
1   001 somedata    moredata
2   000 somedata    moredata
3   000 somedata    moredata
3   001 somedata    moredata
3   002 somedata    moredata

Well, currently what i am doing is, left join b to a and c to a, but i think every time for record in a will be searched in b and c both making it Less cost effective. hence want to make it cost effective/fine-tune such that if records NOT exist in b then only search c.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: data is confiedential kindof stuff but strcture i have shred in question

Comment: @Somesh - Please add desired result too

Comment: definitely not a NORMALIZED database setup, as repeating information is a waste. Also I suggest just to UNION ALL all three tables as the database engine's optimizer will handle the best performance return of all distinct rows.

Comment: added desired data. requirment is simple table a is your base/parent table, search record in table b, if not found in table  b then only search in table c...

Comment: let me tell you this is live production scenario serving transaction of worth million from many years, so i believe it well normalised.

Comment: @SomeshPursnani Just because you have done something for a long time, does not necessarily mean that it's been done right for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a way to "collect" all the rows from table B, and if there are none, then all the rows from table C. Doing the join to A is then standard.

Something like this should work. Make it a subquery and join to your first table.

```
select  col_a, col_b, col_c
  from  table_b
union all
select  col_a, col_b, col_c
  from  table_c
  where (select count(*) from table_b) = 0
```

If `table_b` has at least one row, then nothing will be selected from `table_c` (because the `where` condition will be false for all rows in `table_c`). However, if `table_b` is empty, all the rows from `table_c` will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first create a union of two tables B and C with only those records where are in B and C but if they are in B then we should ignore the C ones then do a join with Table A. Thus:

```
SELECT B.cola, B.colb from B
UNION ALL
SELECT C.cola, C.colb from C
```

Now using this table, you can join with Table A like:

```
SELECT A.cola, A.colb, tmp.colc
FROM A
JOIN
( SELECT B.cola, B.colb, B.colc from B
UNION ALL
SELECT C.cola, C.colb from C) AS tmp
ON A.cola = tmp.cola
AND A.colb = tmp.colb
```

Comment: a UNION ALL does what you are doing by a UNION with an INTERSECT, that being a distinct UNION of nothing repeating.

Comment: The requirement is to join to rows from table C **only if table B is empty**. How does this (or the first version you posted) achieve that?

Comment: @mathguy the question did not mean that the whole table B should be empty. He meant that if you can't find a join in table B for the data (for a particular row), then you search for it in C

Comment: Oh... I see. You may be right; I read it differently (perhaps too literally).

Answer (score 0):

Two left joins:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.* 
from a
left join b
 on a.cola=b.cola
and a.colb = b.colb
left join c
 on a.cola=c.cola
and a.colb=c.colb
```

Comment: i guess it will check for every c in a.

Comment: @SomeshPursnani The join order will depend. To find out, get an execution plan